# How to know whether to use 'that' in clauses like 'I don't want that you go to Ireland'?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

For me, both next sentences are correct :

- I don't want you to go to Ireland.
- I don't want that you go to Ireland.

How do I know whether or not I should use "that" in a sentences like these?

Comment: In the case of the verb "to want," we never use the relative pronoun "that," unlike in the Spanish language, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some verbs, can be followed by *that* clauses, some cannot.

- *I don't want you to go to Ireland.*
  <s>*I don't want that you go to Ireland*.</s> (*want* is not used with a *that* clause.)

There's no easy way to decide if a verb is followed by a *that* clause or not. Mostly, you'll have to learn them as part of a phrase.

Comment: That's right. You just have to learn that (for example) "want" takes an infinitive clause with 'to' (_I want him to go_.); but "desire" can take an infinitive clause with "to" _or_ a finite clause introduced by "that" (_I desire him to go_. _I desire that he goes_ (or _that he go_ - so-called 'subjunctive')), and "wish" can take an infinitive clause with "to" _or_ a finite conditional clause optionally introduced by "that": ( _I wish him to go_. _I wish [that] he would go_.)