# What's the difference between "to verb" and "that S+V"?

Tags: difference

Are these sentences the same in meaning?

> 1. I want ***you to leave*** me alone.
> 2. I want ***that you leave*** me alone.

If not, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to say “want you to do” instead of “want you do”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/why-do-i-have-to-say-want-you-to-do-instead-of-want-you-do) Also [How to know whether to use 'that' in clauses like 'I don't want that you go to Ireland'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82912/) and [I want you to speak English / that you'll speak English / that you speak English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174446/), among others.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers indicates, this has been answered here several times. *Want* does not 'license' finite or gerund-participle clauses as complement, only infinitival clauses.

Comment: @StoneyB: I tentatively considered the possibility that the form [*(I / we / they) **want that you go***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want+that+you+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwant%20that%20you%20go%3B%2Cc0) might perhaps have been more likely a century or two ago. But that linked NGram suggests it's actually become more common ***in recent decades*** (more non-native Anglophones getting into print?). Bizarrely, when I try to drill down into the results there (for any date, or *all*), it can't show me a single one.